# Binary passwords -first occurence

Tags: combinatorics

> How many $12$-digit binary passwords (passwords containing only the numbers $1$ and $0$) have the property that the first occurrence of a triple number (either $000$ or $111$) occurs in the $10^{th}$, $11^{th}$ and $12^{th}$ positions

To answer this question, I did a tree branch and got $110$ binary passwords. I'm not sure if I am correct but I'm trying to find another way to do this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two symmetric possibilities for the last three positions; let's pick $000$ and multiply the result by $2$. Then before those zeros is a bitstring that ends in $1$ and has no more than two identical consecutive digits – call such a bitstring admissible. Let $a_n$ denote the number of admissible bitstrings of length $n$. The admissible bitstrings of length $n$ that begin with two identical digits are in one-to-one correspondence with the admissible bitstrings of length $n-2$ (obtained by removing the initial identical digits), and the admissible bitstrings of length $n$ that don't begin with two identical digits are in one-to-one correspondence with the admissible bitstrings of length $n-1$ (obtained by removing the initial digit). Thus we have the recurrence relation $a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}$. This is the recurrence relation of the Fibonacci numbers, and indeed the initial values are $a_0=1$ and $a_1=1$, so the $a_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers (with index shifted by one), and $a_9=55$, so your count of $2\cdot55=110$ is correct.

Comment: oh wow, totally didn't see that. Super interesting.